# Can't pass values to HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the function I am using to get all the active values on my spreadsheet:

```
function getAllValuesInSheet(){
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
  return values;
}
```

This returns an 2D Array of my values.

In my HtmlService I have:

```
<script>

    function onSuccess(values) {
      console.log("ran");
      console.log(values);
     }

    function populate(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getAllValuesInSheet();
    }


</script>

<script>
  // Using the "load" event to execute the function "populate"
  window.addEventListener('load', populate);
</script>
```

I get an error `Uncaught ScriptError: The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.`

I have functions similar to this one that work perfectly fine.  I wonder if the data is too large to pass? It's not that big it's under 500 cells.

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix this?  I am trying to load all my spreadsheet data to my HtmlService. Is this a bad practice for small data sets? Should I make ajax calls back and forth instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the array to a json format with the function JSON.stringify(object) so the array is easier to treat.

your code would be like:

```
return JSON.stringify(values);
```

Check if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: This is great and works! How does this make the array "easier to treat"? No need for a long explanation, if you know of terms to search for or the idea behind it, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: well probably that was not the best word. But it would be related to the kind of information apps script allows to send. Its better to send a json as a string than the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that Gerardo's answer works is because it ensures that your server-side function returns a String, which is a JavaScript primitive.

Your original request would fail if any of the array contents consisted of unsupported types such as Date objects.

Source: [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)